# Append NSInteger to NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c

How do you append a NSInteger to NSMutableData. Something allong the lines of...

```
NSMutableData *myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSInteger myInteger = 42;

[myData appendBytes:myInteger length:sizeof(myInteger)];
```

So that 0x0000002A will get appended to myData.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pass the address of the integer, not the integer itself.  `appendBytes:length:` expects a pointer to a data buffer and the size of the data buffer.  In this case, the "data buffer" is the integer.

```
[myData appendBytes:&myInteger length:sizeof(myInteger)];
```

Keep in mind, though, that this will use your computer's endianness to encode it.  If you plan on writing the data to a file or sending it across the network, you should use a known endianness instead.  For example, to convert from host (your machine) to network endianness, use [`htonl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl):

```
uint32_t theInt = htonl((uint32_t)myInteger);
[myData appendBytes:&theInt length:sizeof(theInt)];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on ntohl(), it is being sent across the network :)