# How do I set integer endianness using htonl in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set integer endianness using `htonl()` in Swift but the compiler isn't finding the `htonl()` method.

I've been using this as my reference: [Append NSInteger to NSMutableData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716181/append-nsinteger-to-nsmutabledata)

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import CFNetwork
import CoreFoundation

var data = NSMutableData()
var number : UInt32 = 12
var convertedNumber : UInt32 = htonl(number)
data.appendBytes(&convertedNumber, length: 4)
```

I've just been running this in a playground. The error is:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'htonl'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**: Martin R's answer is the correct answer for current versions of Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24653879/195691

--

You should use the `CFSwapInt32HostToBig()` CoreFoundation method, as `htonl` is likely implemented as a C macro that will not work in swift.

However, it looks like this doesn't currently work in the Swift playground. I'm getting the error `Playground execution failed: error: error: Couldn't lookup symbols: __OSSwapInt32` despite the fact that the CoreFoundation documentation now includes method signatures in Swift for its byte swapping methods.

Interestingly, it looks like at least part of `<arpa/inet.h>` has been ported to swift, as methods like `inet_ntoa()` and `inet_addr()` are available to Swift, but the `htonl` family is not.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Looks like this will work. I ended up implementing htonl() in a bridging header / native-c but I'll switch to this.

Comment: Right. htonl/htons etc is a macro and hence not imported into Swift (varargs C funcs like ioctl/fcntl are another common thing missing). If you know the endianess it's easy to reimplement:func ntohs(value: CUnsignedShort) -> CUnsignedShort {
  // hm, htons is not a func in OSX and the macro is not mapped
  return (value << 8) + (value >> 8);
}
let htons = ntohs // same thing, swap bytes :-)

Comment: Actually `CFSwapInt32HostToBig` and friends are available now in the Swift that comes with Xcode 6.1.1 :)

Comment: @MartinR That may be true, but `UInt32.bigEndian`, `UInt32.littleEndian`, and `UInt32.byteSwapped` seem much nicer than using `CFSwapInt32HostToBig`

Comment: PSA  `5.bigEndian.littleEndian` does not equal 5!  However, `CFSwapInt16BigToHost(CFSwapInt16HostToBig(5))` does in fact equal 5!

Answer (score 34):

As of Xcode 6, Beta 3, all integer types have a `bigEndian` method which
returns the big-endian representation of the integer and changes the
byte order if necessary. Example:

```
var data = NSMutableData()
var number : UInt32 = 0x12345678
var convertedNumber = number.bigEndian
data.appendBytes(&convertedNumber, length: 4)
print(data)
// Output: <12345678>
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
let data = NSMutableData()
let number: UInt32 = 0x12345678
var convertedNumber = number.bigEndian
data.append(&convertedNumber, length: 4)
```

Or, using the new `Data` value type:

```
var data = Data()
let number: UInt32 = 0x12345678
var convertedNumber = number.bigEndian
withUnsafePointer(to: &convertedNumber) {
    data.append(UnsafeRawPointer($0).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), count: 4)
}
```

Comment: If you're looking for the opposite direction (network to host), you have `UInt32(bigEndian: number)`, and similar `inits` for other integer types.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using CFSwapInt32HostToBig() as Alex Pretzlav advised you should use

```
CFSwapInt32()
```

instead of

```
ntonl() and ntohl()
```

and

```
CFSwapInt16()
```

instead of

```
ntons() and ntohs()
```

Your code should look like

```
import Foundation
import CFNetwork
import CoreFoundation

var data = NSMutableData()
var number : UInt32 = 12
var convertedNumber : UInt32 = CFSwapInt32(number)
data.appendBytes(&convertedNumber, length: 4)
```

Also there is

```
CFSwapInt64()
```

for 8-byted integer swapping.

**Edit 1**

Of course you should use these functions only on processors with little endian integers cause functions I provided perform bytes swap anyway.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. You say not to use `CFSwapInt32HostToBig`, suggesting you use `CFSwapInt32` instead, followed by " you should use these functions only on processors with little endian integers"... the entire point of `CFSwapInt32HostToBig` is precisely that it swaps, or doesn't, depending on the platform.