# swift 3: How to extend [UInt8] to add getUInt32BE function

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation, swift3

I'm trying to extend `[UInt8]` with `getUInt32BE()` function like below code.

Here's the error that I receive:

> "Cannot subscript a value of type 'Self' with an index of type
>   'Range'"

Could someone help me correct this error?

```swift
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == UInt8 {
    public func getUInt32BE(at: Int = 0) -> UInt32 {
        return self[at..<at+4].reduce(0) {
          $0 << 8 + UInt32($1)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative #1: use `.pointee` property of `UnsafePointer`

As described in the following Q&A

- [Convert a two byte UInt8 array to a UInt16 in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267089/convert-a-two-byte-uint8-array-to-a-uint16-in-swift)

you can use, in Swift 2.2, e.g.

> ```
> UnsafePointer<UInt16>(bytes).memory
> ```

to convert a 2-byte `UInt8` array to a `UInt16` value (host byte order).

Now, in Swift 3.0-dev `.memory` has been replaced by `.pointee`. Applying the above as well as this change, we can likewise use `UnsafePointer<UInt32>(bytes).pointee` to access the `UInt32` representation of a 4-byte `UInt8` array, however noting that the representation uses host byte order for conversion. To possible (if necessary) convert this to the big endian representation of the integer, we can use the `.bigEndian` property available to each integer type, as described in the following Q&A:

- [How do I set integer endianness using htonl in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394615/how-do-i-set-integer-endianness-using-htonl-in-swift/)

This is still valid in Swift 3.0-dev, and consequently, we can construct your `getUInt32BE(...)` method as follows

```swift
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == UInt8 {
    public func getUInt32BE(at: Index.Distance) -> UInt32? {
        let from = startIndex.advanced(by: at, limit: endIndex)
        let to = from.advanced(by: 4, limit: endIndex)
        
        guard case let bytes = Array(self[from..<to]) 
            where bytes.count == 4 else { return nil }
        
        return UnsafePointer<UInt32>(bytes).pointee.bigEndian
    }
}
```

---

### Alternative #2: use bit shifting

Alternatively, using a modified version of the above with bit shifting (similar to the attempt of your question) rather than using `UnsafePointer<..>`:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == UInt8 {

    public func getUInt32BE(at: Index.Distance) -> UInt32? {
        let from = startIndex.advanced(by: at, limit: endIndex)
        let to = from.advanced(by: 4, limit: endIndex)
        
        guard case let bytesSlice = self[from..<to] 
            where from.distance(to: to) == 4 else { return nil }
        
        return bytesSlice.reduce(0) { (tot, val) -> UInt32 in
            tot << 8 + UInt32(val as! UInt8)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we need to help out the compiler by forcibly casting `val` from `Iterator.Element` to `UInt8` (which is guaranteed to succeed due to the `where` clause of the extension; `Iterator.Element == UInt8`).

---

### Example usage

Example usage for any of the two alternatives above:

```
/* example usage */
let bytes: [UInt8] = [
    0,   // 0b 0000 0000
    255, // 0b 1111 1111 
    0,   // 0b 0000 0000
    104, // 0b 0110 1000
    76]  // 0b 0100 1100
    
/*  byteArr[1..<5], big-endian:
        0b 1111 1111 0000 0000 0110 1000 0100 1100 */
let u32verify = 0b11111111000000000110100001001100 
print(u32verify) // 4278216780
    
if let u32val = bytes.getUInt32BE(1) {
    print(u32val) // 4278216780, OK
}
```

For details on the `Collection` protocol (the reason of your error above is not using the associated type `Index.Distance` of this protocol to construct your sub-array), see e.g.

- http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/Collection/

Comment: @yielding Happy to help. Note that I've updated the answer slightly, now using `.bigEndian` property (rather than reversing `bytes` array), whereas the prior answer assumed host byte order was little endian (not very general, but not fixed).